# Scrollable div with absolute content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a `Card` div that is supposed to show the scroll if the content exceeds it's height. I've used `overflow-y: auto` to do that. I'm trying to use a `Select` inside it, and the select menu is supposed to show in front of the card. The menu position is `absolute`.

The problem is, even with `position: absolute`, the menu is taking space inside the card. making it scrollable.

[image]

If I remove the overflow from the card, it works fine, but the content exceeds it. I've created a sandbox for it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/position-absolute-inside-overflow-y-9kppcy?file=/src/App.js

### Other things I have tried

- Show the `SelectMenu` inside a portal.

  - Better results I got so far, but when the window is scrolled, the menu got fixed in the screen.
- Remove the overflow from the card, add it to a `CardBody` element, and keep the select outside it.

  - Did the magic, but with deep nested divs, is really hard to keep it outside every element with overflow.
  - Did not work if the Select is inside a modal (because modals should have a scroll).

### More details

- I'm using [react-select](https://react-select.com/) to create my select, but the problem is strictly css and html.

This might be a common question, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: see this maybe it will be very useful https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ (it is from a blog called `css-tricks`) which describe really your problem, follow what they say and I hope you will solve it soon. good coding day!

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas sadly, it didn't work beacuse both scrolls are in the same direction (y)

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution of using a React Portal actually makes a lot of sense, but you just need a little more trick to position the element.

```
{showMenu &&
  createPortal(
    <div className="SelectMenu" style={menuStyle}>
      I'm the menu.
    </div>,
    PORTAL_HOST_NODE
  )}
```

The `menuStyle` is simply a computed value returned by `useMemo`, which is simply the CSS styles we need to apply to position your menu. What you want is the menu to use `position: fixed`, and then simply use the `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` attributes of the trigger element (in this case, your "Open Select" button) to position the element.

In order to ensure that the position is updated when the viewport is scrolled, you will also need to track the `window.scrollY` value:

```
const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(window.scrollY);

useEffect(() => {
  const onScroll = () => setScrollY(window.scrollY);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  };
}, []);
```

I see that you have a manual `0.5rem` offset you want for the select menu to be positioned away from its trigger element. We can store in as a CSS variable:

```css
.SelectMenu {
  --top-offset: 0.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then, it is matter of setting the other code up as mentioned before. Some notes:

- Use CSS transform so that we can handle sub pixel placement (instead of top/left)
- Set the width so that your select menu follows the width of its trigger element
- Use the CSS custom property set above to calculate the y-axis value of CSS transform

```
const [menuTriggerElementRect, setMenuTriggerElementRect] = useState(null);

const toggleMenu = useCallback((e) => {
  setShowMenu((old) => !old);
  setMenuTriggerElementRect(e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect());
}, []);

const menuStyle = useMemo(() => {
  if (menuTriggerElementRect === null) return {};

  const { top, left, width, height } = menuTriggerElementRect;
  return {
    transform: `translate(${left}px, calc(${
      top + height - scrollY
    }px + var(--top-offset)))`,
    width: `${width}px`
  };
}, [menuTriggerElementRect, scrollY]);
```

See your updated CodeSandbox example here:

[image: Edit Position absolute inside overflow Y (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the overflow for that card only with a modifier class. That should give you your desired result.

[See Fork here](https://codesandbox.io/s/position-absolute-inside-overflow-y-forked-tpcxzs)

Comment: Thats basically what I tried with my "CardBody" class approach. Like I said, doesn't work inside scrollable modals.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The original Code Sandbox link was wrong, it should be working now.

Here's a solution using only CSS, preserving as much functionality of the `Card` class as I could.

[Code Sandbox Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/position-absolute-inside-overflow-y-forked-n4jb3k?file=/src/styles.css)

And here's the CSS:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 4rem; 
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 124px;
}

.Select {
  width: 60vw;
}

.SelectButton {
  all: unset;
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.SelectMenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

A note on using `position: absolute` from this post [Using position:absolute, the nearest positioned ancestor is having no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741657/14111683):

From the post:

> - An absolutely positioned element will be positioned within its containing block, which is defined by the nearest positioned ancestor. However, if there is no positioned ancestor, the containing block is the initial containing block (i.e., the viewport).
> - When you apply position: absolute to an element you remove it from the normal flow. That's it. The element will still be positioned as though it were in the normal flow. It isn't until you apply the CSS offset properties (left, right, top, bottom) that you actually position the element.

So, since in this case there isn't any positioned ancestor, the containing block is the viewport. This allows the `absolute`ly positioned menu to keep its position in the viewport, but if there was more content in the div that caused it to overflow, the menu would not scroll with the div. You can see this behavior by uncommenting some code in `App.js` in the Code Sandbox fork.

I also changed some of the widths to make things look nice, but from a functionality perspective that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I did something similar using position `fixed` instead. It's a good approach but sadly did not have the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `Menu` to be inside the `Card` you can just add an external wrapper and position it relative to that wrapper.

[Code Sandbox Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/position-absolute-inside-overflow-y-forked-7ctjmp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: That's a portal-like approach if we use react. It would be really nice if the menu keeps fixed bellow the button